# How to addClass & addRemove class or change property using .css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, octobercms

I have tried many ways but still not working...

- click the submit button & expand button(tab) to display the chatbot and hide the tab
- click the minimize button(chatbot) to hide the chatbot and display the tab

1) addClass/RemoveClass

default.htm

```
<!-- ------- button ------- -->
<div class="ask-button-container">
    <button id="submit" class="btnSubmit">Ask</button>
</div>

<!-- ------- tab ------- -->
<div id="tab{{__SELF__.id}}" name="{{__SELF__.id}}" class="my-tab">
    <div id="tab-minimize">
        <div id="tab-label"></div>
        <div id="tab-expand{{__SELF__.id}}" class="tab-expand tab-btn"></div>
        <div id="tab-close{{__SELF__.id}}" class="tab-close tab-btn"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- ------- chatbot ------- -->
<div id="chatbot-window-wrapper{{__SELF__.id}}" class="cb-window hidden" style="position: fixed;">
    <div id="control-bar">
        <div id="chatbot-minimize{{__SELF__.id}}" class="minus pull-right chatbot-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></div>
    </div>
    <iframe id="chatbot-window" name="chatbot-window" scroll="" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="2" src="{{ 'page1'|page }}"></iframe>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){

    $(".tab-close").click(function() {        
        $(this).closest(".my-tab").addClass("hidden");   //working
    }); 

    $(".tab-expand").click(function() {        
    var chatbot = $(this).closest(".cb-window");
    chatbot.removeClass("hidden");
    $(this).closest(".my-tab").addClass("hidden");    //working
    });

    $(".btnSubmit").click(function() {   
    var chatbot = $(this).closest(".cb-window");
        chatbot.removeClass("hidden");
        $(this).closest(".my-tab").addClass("hidden");
    });

    $(".minus").click(function() {
    var chatbot = $(this).closest(".cb-window");
        chatbot.addClass("hidden");
        $(this).closest(".my-tab").removeClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

---

2) .css

```
$(this).closest(".cb-window").css("visibility", "visible");
```

Can someone please show me how to do it? Thank you.
or any other ways using jquery? .show/.hide , .toggle?

Comment: could you please elaborate your question. there are so many codes.

Comment: where is the element with my-tab class??

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with your way of reaching the proper `element` and your understanding on **[`closest`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp)** option of `jquery`.

> **As per definition** - *The **[`closest()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp)** method returns the first ancestor of the selected element. An ancestor is a parent, grandparent,
>   great-grandparent, and so on*.

When you say `closest` on `btnSubmit` click event, the `.cb-window` was never its **ancestor** so `$(this).closest('.cb-window')` would basically fail. You need to traverse back to `btnSubmit`'s parent who will be `sibling` of `.cb-window` and then you can easily get that element. Below is how you can achieve it. Also, you do not need multiple `$(function(){` which is equivalent to `$(document).ready` and only one is sufficient.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btnSubmit").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".ask-button-container").siblings('.cb-window').removeClass("hidden");
    //closest ancestor would be .ask-button-container and its sibling is .cb-window
    $(this).closest(".my-tab").addClass("hidden");
    //did not find .my-tab element in your `html`
  });

  $(".minus").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.cb-window').addClass("hidden");
    $(this).closest(".my-tab").removeClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="ask-button-container">
  <button id="submit" class="btnSubmit">Ask</button>
</div>

<div id="chatbot-window-wrapper{{__SELF__.id}}" class="cb-window hidden" style="position: fixed;">
  <div id="control-bar">
    <div id="chatbot-minimize{{__SELF__.id}}" class="minus pull-right chatbot-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></div>
    </div>
    <iframe id="chatbot-window" name="chatbot-window" scroll="" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="2" src="{{ 'page1'|page }}"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem that you don't target the element you want in a right way .. you need to use

```js
$(function(){

    $(".tab-close").click(function() {        
        $(this).closest(".my-tab").addClass("hidden");   //working
    }); 

    $(".tab-expand").click(function() {        
    var chatbot = $(this).closest('.my-tab').next(".cb-window");
    chatbot.removeClass("hidden");
    $(this).closest(".my-tab").addClass("hidden");    //working
    });

    $(".btnSubmit").click(function() {   
    var chatbot = $(this).closest('div').next().next(".cb-window");
        chatbot.removeClass("hidden");
        $(this).closest('div').next(".my-tab").addClass("hidden");
    });

    $(".minus").click(function() {
    var chatbot = $(this).closest(".cb-window");
        chatbot.addClass("hidden");
        chatbot.prev(".my-tab").removeClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display : none;
}
.minus{
  padding : 5px;
  background : red;
  color: #fff;
  text-align : center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- ------- button ------- -->
<div class="ask-button-container">
    <button id="submit" class="btnSubmit">Ask</button>
</div>

<!-- ------- tab ------- -->
<div id="tab{{__SELF__.id}}" name="{{__SELF__.id}}" class="my-tab">
    <div id="tab-minimize">
        <div id="tab-label"></div>
        <div id="tab-expand{{__SELF__.id}}" class="tab-expand tab-btn"></div>
        <div id="tab-close{{__SELF__.id}}" class="tab-close tab-btn"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- ------- chatbot ------- -->
<div id="chatbot-window-wrapper{{__SELF__.id}}" class="cb-window hidden" style="position: fixed;">
    <div id="control-bar">
        <div id="chatbot-minimize{{__SELF__.id}}" class="minus pull-right chatbot-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign">-</span></div>
    </div>
    <iframe id="chatbot-window" name="chatbot-window" scroll="" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="2" src="{{ 'page1'|page }}"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: yea I have tried but not working... and the {{__SELF__.id}} is important in my code

Answer (score 0):

When we click or do operation on an element we can add or remove class and you can try like this.

```
$('#elm').hover(
   function(){ $(this).addClass('hover') },
   function(){ $(this).removeClass('hover') }
)
```